# Wordpress rewrite rule not working

Tags: url-rewriting

```
www.xyz.com/place?id=(variable)
```

which I would like in the format:

```
www.xyz.com/places/(variable)

www.xyz.com/tags?id=(variable)
```

which I would like in the format:

```
www.xyz.com/type/(variable)

www.xyz.com/things-to-do-in?id=(variable)
```

which I would like in the format:

```
www.xyz.com/things-to-do-in-(variable)
```

I tried

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^http://www.xyz.com/things-to-do-in-([^/]*)/?',
    'http://xyz.com/things-to-do-in?id=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
```

but its not working. What should I do?